# Random posts in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php

I have 30 divs with different images and links and wanted to get them to be displayed in 10 different divs randomly.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGPFM.jpg (it's an animated gif)

Something like a "random related posts" that we use in wordpress, but my page is not in wordpress. It's just a simple website in php.

the div would be so
   Link  
   Link  
   Link  
etc
etc
etc

How to do this in javascript or php?

Answer (score 0):

Create 10 divs with those positions (empty divs)

Create a string array with the 10 (or more) html content that will fill the divs

Shuffle the array as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Pass by the array and modify the innerHtml of the 10 divs one by one (Only first 10 elements since only 10 divs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use different ways, depending on your needs. When using MySQL you can use a query like:

```
SELECT images, link FROM tablename WHERE ...... ORDER BY RAND()
```

Or you can use shuffle on an array.

```
$array = array ( 'image1', 'image2' );
shuffle ( $array );

// Display divs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="divPool">content 1</div>
<div class="divPool">content 2</div>
<div class="divPool">content 3</div>
```

etc... to 30 divs

```
<div class="destination">destination 1</div>
<div class="destination">destination 2</div>
<div class="destination">destination 3</div>
```

etc. to 10 divs,

then in JavaScript:

```
    //make arrays of the html elements in each class:
    var arrayOfContent=document.getElementsByClassName("divPool");
    var arrayOfDestinations=document.getElementsByClassName("destination");

    for (var i=0; i<10: i++){//for each of the 10 destination divs

    //select a random number from 0 to 29
    var random=Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);

    arrayOfDestinations[i].innerHTML=arrayOfContent[random].innerHTML
    }
```

Also, in css you can make the divPool class invisible like this:

```
.divPool{display:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
  var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
  $("#display_"+id).show();
 }    
});
</script>
<div id="display_1" style="display:none;">1</div>
<div id="display_2" style="display:none;">2</div>
<div id="display_3" style="display:none;">3</div>
<div id="display_4" style="display:none;">4</div>
<div id="display_5" style="display:none;">5</div>
<div id="display_6" style="display:none;">6</div>
<div id="display_7" style="display:none;">7</div>
<div id="display_8" style="display:none;">8</div>
<div id="display_9" style="display:none;">9</div>
<div id="display_10" style="display:none;">10</div>
<div id="display_11" style="display:none;">11</div>
<div id="display_12" style="display:none;">12</div>
<div id="display_13" style="display:none;">13</div>
<div id="display_14" style="display:none;">14</div>
<div id="display_15" style="display:none;">15</div>
<div id="display_16" style="display:none;">16</div>
<div id="display_17" style="display:none;">17</div>
<div id="display_18" style="display:none;">18</div>
<div id="display_19" style="display:none;">19</div>
<div id="display_20" style="display:none;">20</div>
<div id="display_21" style="display:none;">21</div>
<div id="display_22" style="display:none;">22</div>
<div id="display_23" style="display:none;">23</div>
<div id="display_24" style="display:none;">24</div>
<div id="display_25" style="display:none;">25</div>
<div id="display_26" style="display:none;">26</div>
<div id="display_27" style="display:none;">27</div>
<div id="display_28" style="display:none;">28</div>
<div id="display_29" style="display:none;">29</div>
<div id="display_30" style="display:none;">30</div>
```

`

Comment: hello, thanks for you help .it was just what I needed, however encountered a problem:Because sometimes appears 10 divs, but sometimes appear only 9 divs?
f5 gave several times, and found it. How to fix it?

Comment: Its because of duplicate random number.

Comment: In for loop you have check if div already display than create new random number